# How to release memory after flex application is closed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

How to release memory when browser is closed.

The problem is when I run my flex application in browser.
After closing the browser the memory is not released.

When re-open the application in browser the memory usage becomes doubled

During third time it became triple .Like that it is going..

How to effectively do memory management in flex

Comment: What are your browser/version/OS? Do you use the flash player debug? How do you know the memory is not released?

Comment: I take a release build of my project ..When i run the application i checked the task manager. The browser was IE

Comment: So iexplorer is still executed when you close it?...

Comment: This sounds like there is an unhandled error happening at some point.

Comment: Hi amy..Let me check whether any error is happening in debug mode

Comment: I am passing a value from flashvars to the swf ..whether that can cause any issues like this ?

Comment: @kodiak My app is loaded as a viewer.Its loaded when user clicks a link.So there is only one tab opened at a time.When i close my app the iexplorer also closes

Comment: Memory is generally not released until it's needed for something else. There is no set interval for releasing memory because it uses CPU to do it and you don't want the CPU regularly running a single process. Open up a few heavy apps (if you have the CS suite, open a few of those) and see if the memory is released. Beyond that, there is no way for a non-AIR app to know when it is being closed (other than the DEACTIVATED event which won't work here) and no way to force run Garbage Collection outside of debug mode in AIR

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 .What you said is correct. But i checked with other applications.Memory allocated for those are getting released after exiting the browser, Issue is happening with this application only

Comment: Does the memory eventually get released? My guess is the Flash Plugin process is still running, therefore the memory doesn't get released. You aren't running an application; you are running a sub-application that is running in another application. So my guess is memory doesn't get released entirely until the Flash Plugin's process is ended or Flash runs a self-collection.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 .Yes i am running my application as a sub application. So whats your suggestion? I have to run a self collection inside flex or ?

Comment: No, you don't understand. Flash Player is the application. The memory belongs to the Player, not to your app. Your app is running inside of the Player. My guess is the memory isn't released until the Player itself either A) Runs Garbage Collection on itself or B) Is quit. It's worth noting that just because it is using memory, does not mean it is occupying memory. The OS reserves memory for each program until another program needs it. Again, native applications may be able to force the OS to release that memory but you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

normally you don't need to worry about that. the garbage collector is there. its possibly not releasing immediately, because there are plenty of free memory, and your OS/browser waits while its not needed.

Comment: Its not releasing memory even after 5 min ..staying with the same memory usage

Comment: okay, but can you open and close it until system runs out of memory?

Comment: hi csomakk ..I can open again and close it until system runs out of memory. so each time when i opens the memory is increased by 100%

Comment: but what happens when you use all your ram?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug, worth looking it up on https://bugbase.adobe.com/?event=search

I could do this if I knew your Flash version.

Comment: Well, it could have existed in earlier versions too, right? Can't find it in bug base. It will be very kind of you to try installing older versions of Flash Player one by one and figuring out the exact version where this bug was introduced. Bug may repro only on some SWFs (e.g. those that use video or mic).